# Not all content is animated inside a stack view when hiding it

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm currently working on a iOS (swift 3) app. I have a simple vertical stack view containing 2 horizontal stack views. In some cases I want to hide the bottom one. I do so by using the following code

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
                self.bottomStackView.isHidden = true;
 };
```

The animation shown below doesn't really do what I would expect:

[image]

While the border of the buttons is animated properly when hiding, the text inside each button doesn't seem to be affected until the very end. Any idea as to how I could fix this?

Comment: I'd say don't rely on the hiding of the stack view to perform the animation for you.

Comment: After much research, it seams like stack can handle animations ok, but other items such as buttons might have problems. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What I usually do is to animate the alpha to 0 as well as doing the hiding, looks good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kept doing some research on the subject, and it seems like most [articles](https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2) were suggesting that using stacks to perform animation would work fine. However I have also found that animations would only work with [animatable properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html), *isHidden* not being one of them.

In the end after some trial and errors I have found that *isHidden* can be animated with stack views, but you can expect children to misbehave. So far the only workaround I have found is like so:

```
        let duration = 0.5;
        let delay = 0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, animations: {
            self.bottomStack.isHidden = self.hideBottomStack;
        })
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration/2, delay: delay, animations: {
            self.bottomStack.alpha = 0;
        })
```

You'll note here that I basically "turn" the alpha property down to 0 in half the time I take to hide the stack. This has the effect to hide the text before it overlaps with the upper stack. Also note that I could also have decided to do something like this:

```
       UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, animations: {
           self.bottomStack.alpha = 0;
       }, completion: { (_) in 
           self.bottomStack.isHidden = true;
       })
```

This would also hide the bottom stack, but you lose the hiding motion in favor of a fading motion and hide the stack once the fading is done.

Comment: I have faced same issue with my stack view. Its not applying the animation to the subviews inside. In iOS 10 it works without any problem but in iOS 11 the animation is not proper. Thanks I used this workaround for fixing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about this, I think stackviews can cause weird behaviour sometimes. Have you tried adding "self.view.layoutIfNeeded()" inside the UIView.animate block? Like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
      self.bottomStackView.isHidden = true
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I think it should also work if you put the "self.bottomStackView.isHidden = true" above the UIView.animate, not sure though, not an expert at it.
Also, I don't think you need to use ";" after your line of code in swift :)

Comment: I tried layoutIfNeeded without success. You've got a point about the ";". I'm just always coding in other languages that require it, so it's like a habit I can't get rid of ^^